# Android Listview Item is Repeating on adding new item with different data

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am trying working on listactivity in it i am adding items to listview rows . but when i load different data to add an item in list view it repeats the same item added before .

here is my baseadapter class:

```
public class MyNotiAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    String[] data;
    String time; 
    String Name ;
    String Number;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public MyNotiAdapter(Context context, String[] data,String time, String Name ,String Number) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.time = time;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Number=Number;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

     return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

     return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder mHolder;
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, null);

        mHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mHolder.text= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.lablel);
        mHolder.Nameo = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.person);
        mHolder.Numbero = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.edu);
        mHolder.Time = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tym);
        vi.setTag(mHolder);



        mHolder.text.setText(data[position]);
        mHolder.Nameo.setText(Name);
        mHolder.Numbero.setText(Number);
        mHolder.Time.setText(time);

    }else {
            mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return vi;
    }


    public class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public TextView Nameo;
        public TextView Numbero;
        public TextView Time;


    }


}
```

and here is the activity in which i am setting adapter data...

```
 public class noticall extends ListActivity {


    CustomDateTimePicker custom;
    TextView tv,tv1;
    EditText ed;
    String store;
    static String Names;
    public static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;
    String [] adi ;
    static int incre=0;
    ArrayList<String> myrows = new ArrayList<String>();
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    ListView listview;
    String temp1 ,temp2 ;
    int x=0; 
    OnItemClickListener listener;
    String Date,Time,Name,Number;
    MyNotiAdapter adp;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.notify);
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

           listview.setDividerHeight(5);


            custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(noticall.this,new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

               @Override
               public void onCancel() { 
                   finish();
               }


               @Override
               public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                            String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                            String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                            int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec,
                            String AM_PM) {

                      Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();
                      calendar.set(year, monthNumber, date, hour24,  min, 0);

                      long when = calendar.getTimeInMillis();         // notification time

                      Intent myIntent = new Intent(noticall.this, MyReceiver.class);
                      pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(noticall.this, 0, myIntent,0);

                      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);



        //temp1=  store =calendarSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + (monthNumber+1) + "/" + 
    //  year + ", " + hour12 + ":" + min + " " + AM_PM;


        Date = calendarSelected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + (monthNumber+1) + "/" +year; 
        Time = hour12 + ":" + min + " " + AM_PM;

        Log.e("Timeee", Time+"");


        setlisto(Date);

        Toast.makeText(noticall.this, store, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }
    });      


        /*   
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
             startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_CONTACT);

           /**
             * Pass Directly current time format it will return AM and PM if you set
             * false
             */
            custom.set24HourFormat(false);
            /**
             * Pass Directly current data and time to show when it pop up
             */
            custom.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());

            //custom.showDialog();


                findViewById(R.id.button_date).setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_CONTACT);
                        custom.showDialog();
                        incre++;
                        }
                    });

         // ((BaseAdapter) listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged() ;
         // listview.getAdapter().notifyAll();
    }


     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
     {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){

            if (requestCode == 1)
            {
                // Get the URI that points to the selected contact
                Uri contactUri = data.getData();

                // We only need the NUMBER column, because there will be only one row in the result
                String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID};

                String[] segments = contactUri.toString().split("/");
                String id = segments[segments.length - 1];

                // Perform the query on the contact to get the NUMBER column
                // We don't need a selection or sort order (there's only one result for the given URI)
                // CAUTION: The query() method should be called from a separate thread to avoid blocking
                // your app's UI thread. (For simplicity of the sample, this code doesn't do that.)
                // Consider using CursorLoader to perform the query.
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
                {
                    int cid = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID);
                    String contactid = cursor.getString(cid);

                    if (contactid.equals(id))
                    {
                        // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
                        int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                        String number = cursor.getString(column);

                        // Retrieve the contact name from the DISPLAY_NAME column
                        int column_name = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                        String name = cursor.getString(column_name);

                        // Do something with the phone number...
                       // Toast.makeText(this, "I added the Contact: \n" + name + " " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       // ed.setText(name+" - "+number);

                      Name=  Names=name;
                      Number =number;  



                    }

                 cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                cursor.close();

               }
            }
        }


     public void setlisto(String one ){

     Log.e("setlistoo",one+"");
     myrows.add(one);
     adi = myrows.toArray(new String[myrows.size()]);
     listview.setAdapter(new MyNotiAdapter(noticall.this, adi,Time,Name,Number));


    // ((BaseAdapter) listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); 
     //listview.invalidateViews();

     x++;

  }

}
```

i have gone through all the solutions provided on internet . i think i am making some mistake somewhere . if anyone can found where the problem lies...?

**i Have noticed only Data[] array is updating with different values. but other String variables are overwriting on every item i add.. why is this happening ?**

Comment: can you provide myrows object class?

Comment: edited and added the class

Comment: @AlZill i think when add the new data to adapter it adds the new data on previously added items as wel..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay i have solved it by myself . the problem was i was passing simple string but i have to pass string array in order to add new data to listviews.

here are the changes i made ..

in activity:

```
public void setlisto(String one ){

     Log.e("setlistoo",one+"");
     myrows.add(one);
    time1.add(Time);
    name1.add(Name);
    number1.add(Number);


     adi = myrows.toArray(new String[myrows.size()]);
     adi1=time1.toArray(new String[time1.size()]);
     adi2=name1.toArray(new String[name1.size()]);
     adi3=number1.toArray(new String[number1.size()]);
     listview.setAdapter(new MyNotiAdapter(noticall.this, adi,adi1,adi2,adi3));

    // if(adi!=null)
      //adp.notifyDataSetChanged();

     x++;

  }
```

in baseadapter class :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder mHolder;
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, null);

        mHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mHolder.text= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.lablel);
        mHolder.Nameo = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.person);
        mHolder.Numbero = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.edu);
        mHolder.Time = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tym);
        vi.setTag(mHolder);



        mHolder.text.setText(data[position]);
        mHolder.Nameo.setText(Name[position]);
        mHolder.Numbero.setText(Number[position]);
        mHolder.Time.setText(time[position]);

    }else {
            mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return vi;
    }
```

everything goes smooth now ... its working perfect . it might help someone like me . Cheers..

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do call notifyDataSetChanged method and before adding data dynamically call ones setAdapter.

or you can go through this link http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/

Comment: i have tried using notifydatasetchanged  but it didn't help .. if you can see my code . probably u can find the mistake i am making . i will be thankful ..

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems need to be refactored a lot.

- Okay First, create an Model Object class, let say MyReminderObject.java :

  ```
  public class MyReminderObject {
    public String date;
    public String time;
    public String name;
    public String number;
  }
  ```
- In your Adapter :

  Add a list of MyReminderObject.

  ```
  private List<MyReminderObject> mList;
  ```

  Add a new constructor :

  ```
  public MyNotiAdapter(Context context) {
    mList = new ArrayList<MyReminderObject>();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }
  ```

  Change some methods :

  ```
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
  }
  ```

  In your getView method, change some codes :

  ```
  MyReminderObject item = mList.get(position);
  mHolder.text.setText(item.date);
  mHolder.Nameo.setText(item.name);
  mHolder.Numbero.setText(item.number);
  mHolder.Time.setText(item.time);
  ```

  Still in you adapter, add a function to add item :

  ```
  public void addReminder(MyReminderObject item){
     mList.add(item);
     notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
  ```
- In your Activity :

  in your onCreate() :

  ```
  listview.setDividerHeight(5);
  adp = new MyNotiAdapter(noticall.this);
  listview.setAdapter(adp);
  ```

  Lastly, on your setListTo() method :

  ```
  public void setlisto(String one ){

    Log.e("setlistoo",one+"");
    MyReminderObject newItem = new MyReminderObject();
    newItem.date = one;
    newItem.time = Time;
    newItem.name = Name;
    newItem.number = Number;

    adp.addReminder(newItem);

    x++;

  }
  ```

Comment: i got your point . yes i code roughly it needs to be refactored but i had to do it later . for now i just wanted the functionality to work . your answer is good . it helps a lot .. thank you